# How can I put toast messages in a separate file when unsing Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-toasted

I'm using Vue.js and I have toast messages that are hard coded in the 'main.js' and needs to be moved to another separate file. I tried using an external file and importing vue and the needed file for that purpose but failed to make it work.

I also like to note that the toasts are registered in main.js and not in a component.
Here's the separate file's code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted'
Vue.use(VuePreview)
Vue.use(Toasted)
Vue.toasted.register('loginError', 'Wrong Email or password!', {
  type: 'error',
  duration: 2000
})
Vue.toasted.register('noInternet', 'No Internet Connection!', {
  type: 'error',
  duration: 2000
})
Vue.toasted.register('unknownError', 'Something went wrong!', {
  type: 'error',
  duration: 2000
})
```

Comment: Please add code samples of what you tried and detail exactly what isn't working (include any errors you may be getting).  As currently written, this question will most likely get closed as being too broad.

Comment: @patrickSteele I I hope it's more detailed and understandable now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an external file and import that file into your main.js.

**toasts.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted'

Vue.toasted.register('loginError', 'Wrong Email or password!', {
  type: 'error',
  duration: 2000
})
Vue.toasted.register('noInternet', 'No Internet Connection!', {
  type: 'error',
  duration: 2000
})
Vue.toasted.register('unknownError', 'Something went wrong!', {
  type: 'error',
  duration: 2000
})
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import "./toasts"


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Then you can use the registered toasts like this in Vue:

```
this.$toasted.global.loginError()
this.$toasted.global.noInternet()
this.$toasted.global.unknownError()
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/p6q5mj6mj).

Comment: Thanks man it absolutely worked .. although i didn't call "Vue.use()" which is kinda not expected

Comment: @MazenSharkawy It's possible it is not necessary. I did not read through *all* of the vue-toasted documentation. Looks like you are right :) I went ahead and removed it.